# Rendering a partial from Draper Decorator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator, draper

I have a decorator that returns either a string, or a collection.

In my view, I want to display the return of this decorator method.

```
class MyDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def stuff
    if condition
      'some string'
    else
      render model.some_collection
    end
  end
end
```

Now in my view I want to render the string if it's a string, or render the collection.

```
= my_object.stuff
```

Unfortunately I cannot access the `render` method inside `Draper::Decorator`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From https://github.com/drapergem/draper#accessing-helpers:

> Normal Rails helpers are still useful for lots of tasks. Both Rails' provided helper and those defined in your app can be accessed via the h method

So, replace `render` with `h.render` and it should work fine.

Comment: I haven't had an opportunity to implement that fix yet, thank you for your answer. I will mark it as complete once I verify that it works. I can't believe I missed that in the Readme...

Answer (score 2):

you can include Draper's `Draper::LazyHelpers` module inside the decorator to use the `ActionView::Helpers` and the rest of ActionView as you've always have with views.